# How to set beamer Berkeley margins?

Tags: beamer

Could I know how to set the width of the left margin of the Berkeley theme please? (that is where the section titles appear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of the bar can be set with the `width=` option passed to the `\usetheme{Berkeley}` command. In this example I've set it unreasonably wide for demonstration purposes. You can set the size of the text in the sidebar using `\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size= ...}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=2in]{Berkeley} 
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\Huge}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks could you also tell me how to set the text size of only the text that appear in that bar (the section titles) please?

Comment: @MLT I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Also could you tell me how to get slide numbers on the header in Berkeley please? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145829/slide-number-in-beamer-berkeley-header