# Removing some slide numbers in Beamer class Berkeley?

Tags: beamer, slideshow

Using exactlay the code provided here: [Slide number in beamer Berkeley header?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145829/slide-number-in-beamer-berkeley-header/145899#145899) 
I inserted slide numbers. However, I do not want them for some slides (mostly back-up slides): Could you please help me?
What I tried but did not work:

```latex
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{dcolumn}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{spy}


 \usetheme{Berkeley}
 \makeatletter
 \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-\beamer@headheight%
    \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
        \vfil
        \leftskip=-\beamer@leftmargin%
        \advance\leftskip by0.3cm%
        \rightskip=-\beamer@rightmargin%
        \advance\rightskip by0.3cm plus1fil%
        {\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}
            \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\hfill\insertframenumber\par}% added number
        {\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}
            \usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\par}%
        \vbox{}%
        \vskip-1em%
        \vfil
    }%
 }
 \makeatother
 \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
 \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[triangle]



 \begin{document}



\begin{frame}{Numbered slide}

I am a slide that wants a number. 

\end{frame}



\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{No Number}
Here should be no number. 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Comment: thank you @erik

Answer (score 1):

You've redefined frametitle to include the frame number, but you haven't made that conditional on the `noframenumbering` option. To change this, you can redefine `frametitle` to omit the frame number for `\ifbeamer@noframenumbering`. Try the following in your example.

```
 \makeatletter
 \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-\beamer@headheight%
    \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
        \vfil
        \leftskip=-\beamer@leftmargin%
        \advance\leftskip by0.3cm%
        \rightskip=-\beamer@rightmargin%
        \advance\rightskip by0.3cm plus1fil%
        {\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}
            \usebeamerfont{frametitle}
            \ifbeamer@noframenumbering%
            \insertframetitle\par% added number
            \else
            \insertframetitle\hfill\insertframenumber\par% added number
            \fi}
        {\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}
            \usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\par}%
        \vbox{}%
        \vskip-1em%
        \vfil
    }%
 }
 \makeatother
```